# ASP.Net - Static TableHeaderRow and Dynamic Tablerows, THR disappeared and CSS problem

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net, tableheader

I've got two problems here.

**1) Static TableHeaderRow has disappeared**

This is my table:

```html
        <asp:table id="tbEdit" runat="server" style="width: 100%;">
            <asp:TableHeaderRow id="th_Row">
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Scope" />
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Site ID" />
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Site Name" />
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Address" />
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="CAP/ZIP" />
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="City" />
                <asp:TableHeaderCell Scope="Column" Text="Country" />
            </asp:TableHeaderRow>
        </asp:table>
```

In the page load event I'm calling a subroutine to dynamically create tablerows, tablecells, various controls and fill in the values.

This is an extract of that subroutine:

```html
        For y = 0 To i
            While myReader.Read

                Dim tr As New TableRow
                tbEdit.Rows.Add(tr)
                tr.ID = "tr" & y
                For z = 0 To 6
                    Select Case z
                        Case = 0
                            Dim tc As New TableCell
                            Dim ddl As New DropDownList
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells.Add(tc)
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells(z).Controls.Add(ddl)
                            ddl.ID = "ddlScope" & y & "-" & z
                            For x = 0 To iScopes
                                ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem(Scope(x).Name, Scope(x).ID.ToString))
                            Next
                            ddl.SelectedValue = myReader.Item(1)

                        Case = 1
                            Dim tc As New TableCell
                            Dim lbl As New Label
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells.Add(tc)
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells(z).Controls.Add(lbl)
                            lbl.ID = "lblSid" & y & "-" & z
                            lbl.Text = myReader.Item(2)

                        Case = 2
                            Dim tc As New TableCell
                            Dim tbx As New TextBox
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells.Add(tc)
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells(z).Controls.Add(tbx)
                            tbx.ID = "tbxSname" & y & "-" & z
                            tbx.Text = myReader.Item(3)

                        Case = 3
                            Dim tc As New TableCell
                            Dim tbx As New TextBox
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells.Add(tc)
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells(z).Controls.Add(tbx)
                            tbx.ID = "tbxAddress" & y & "-" & z
                            tbx.Text = myReader.Item(4)

                        Case = 4
                            Dim tc As New TableCell
                            Dim tbx As New TextBox
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells.Add(tc)
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells(z).Controls.Add(tbx)
                            tbx.ID = "tbxCap" & y & "-" & z
                            tbx.Text = myReader.Item(5)

                        Case = 5
                            Dim tc As New TableCell
                            Dim tbx As New TextBox
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells.Add(tc)
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells(z).Controls.Add(tbx)
                            tbx.ID = "tbxCity" & y & "-" & z
                            tbx.Text = myReader.Item(6)

                        Case = 6
                            Dim tc As New TableCell
                            Dim ddl As New DropDownList
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells.Add(tc)
                            tbEdit.Rows.Item(y).Cells(z).Controls.Add(ddl)
                            ddl.ID = "ddlCountry" & y & "-" & z
                            For x = 0 To iCountries
                                ddl.Items.Add(New ListItem(Country(x).Name, Country(x).ID.ToString))
                            Next
                            ddl.SelectedValue = myReader.Item(7)

                    End Select
                Next
            End While
        Next
```

Tablerows and controls are created and filled the correct way, everything works as expected but the fact that the TableHeaderRow (that is supposed to be static), doesn't appear. I would like to avoid to create it dynamically since it doesn't make much sense. Can anyone explain the reason why this happens?

**2) tbEdit CSS are ignored**

Originally my table tbEdit was a simple client side html table and I had the following CSS code arranged (it was working fine):

```html
    #tbEdit table { 
            /* border-collapse: collapse; */
            width: 100%; 
            border: 1px solid #868583;
    } 
          
    #tbEdit th, #tbEdit td { 
            text-align: center; 
            padding: 8px;
            border: 1px solid #868583;
    } 
          
    #tbEdit tr:nth-child(1) { 
            background-color: #5D7B9D;
            text-align: center; 
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: white;
            border: 1px solid #868583;
    } 
    #tbEdit tr:nth-child(even):not(:first-child) { 
            background-color: #F7F6F2;
            border: 1px solid #868583;
    }
```

Then I had to transform tbEdit into an ASP control, from that point on the specific CSS has been ignored, totally not taken into consideration. Is there anything I should change in my CSS in order to bind it to an ASP control?

Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Regards, Luca

Comment: I have solved issue nr.1, tbEdit.Rows.Item(y) was overwriting the header at y = 0.
Here the fix: For y = 1 To i + 1
Anyone can help for the CSS problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opted to use the style property of rows and cells to dynamically attribute the CSS.

Like this:

```html
        'CSS TableEdit
        With tbEdit.Style
            .Add("width", "100%")
            .Add("border", "1px solid #868583")
            .Add("text-align", "center")
            .Add("padding", "8px")
        End With

        'CSS TableHeaderRow
        With tbEdit.Rows(0).Style
            .Add("background-color", "#5D7B9D")
            .Add("text-align", "center")
            .Add("vertical-align", "center")
            .Add("color", "white")
            .Add("border", "1px solid #868583")
        End With

        'CSS TableHeaderCells
        For w = 0 To 6
            With tbEdit.Rows(0).Cells(w).Style
                .Add("text-align", "center")
                .Add("padding", "8px")
                .Add("border", "1px solid #868583")
            End With
        Next
```